# Rails Streaming not Streaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working to add a streaming component to my rails app as I'd like to start using SSEs. I have tried getting this to work in a smaller example but am still having trouble. I have been having trouble actually getting rails to properly stream a response to a curl request. I am following the tutorial at http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html. I'm not sure if there is something I have to configure for OSX or if there is something I'm missing in my configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am running this locally on OSX. When I run `curl -i localhost:3000` I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Last-Modified: Wed Apr 23 23:10:15 2014
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: request_method=GET; path=/
X-Request-Id: 89f2af3e-76e9-4873-85b0-3b6fe45f6343
X-Runtime: 0.001724
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

The problem is I get it all at once instead of getting bits of the response as is expected. Please let me know if I need to provide more information

My code is as follows:

**stream_test_controller.rb**

```
class StreamTestController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def index
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    10.times {
      logger.info "hello world sent"
      response.stream.write "hello world\n"
      sleep 1
    }
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'  
ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'puma'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

**development.rb**

```
StreamTest::Application.configure do

  config.preload_frameworks = true
  config.allow_concurrency = true
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development    
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Comment: just to check, does your curl command take 10 seconds to run?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, and even added a logger file each iteration, and it definitely fully runs before I get anything to the curl command.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#streaming-considerations), are you using WEBrick to test?

> WEBrick servers buffer all responses, and so including
>   ActionController::Live will not work. You must use a web server which
>   does not automatically buffer responses.

Comment: Probably not. His Gemfile includes the puma gem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using puma. I've also tried starting the server with the puma command but this didn't help.

Comment: @rsaris As in `rails s Puma`?

Comment: I usually just do rails s but it seems to boot up in the same way as doing rails s Puma. I have also tried starting it with the puma command and it does not work any differently with the curl command.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling buffering in your curl command. From the manpage:

> -N, --no-buffer
>
> Disables the buffering of the output stream. In normal work situations,
>   curl  will  use a standard buffered output stream that
>   will have the effect that it will output the data in chunks, not
>   necessarily  exactly  when  the data arrives.  Using this option
>   will disable that buffering.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this running `curl --no-buffer -i localhost:3000` and `curl --no-buffer localhost:3000` to no avail. Seems like it isn't the buffering of curl that's causing this problem. I've also tried this with chrome and haven't had any success either.

Answer (score 0):

SSE messages are delimited by two newlines ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format)).

Your code should have:

```
response.stream.write "hello world\n\n"
```