# Server-sent events in Rails not delivered asynchronously

Tags: api, server-sent-events, ruby-on-rails-6, puma

I'm trying to write an API that delivers server-sent events using `ActionController::Live::SSE` in Rails 6. In order to understand how the tests would best be written, I started with essentially [copying the trivial example seen here](https://dev.to/isalevine/help-needed-understanding-rails-actioncontroller-live-module-and-async-limitations-4em8):
`my_controller.rb`:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::Live
  def capture
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
    3.times do
      sse.write({message: "Awaiting confirmation ..."})
      sleep 2
    end
    fake_response  = { #The response as hash.
     "annotation_id"=>nil,
     "domain"=>"some.random.com",
     "id"=>2216354,
     "path"=>"/flummoxer/",
     "protocol"=>"https",
    }
    sse.write(fake_response, event: 'successful capture')
  rescue => e
    sse.write(e.message, event: 'something broke: ')
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

When I send a curl request (whether I make it POST or GET) to this endpoint the response arrives all in one chunk, rather than as separate responses:

```
$ curl -i -X GET -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "https://some.random.com/flummoxer"}' http://localhost:3000/capture
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: W/"a24048695d2feca40232467f0fbb410a"
X-Request-Id: 648a5229-a43d-40d3-82fd-1c4ea6fe19cc
X-Runtime: 24.082528
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

event: successful capture
data: {"annotation_id":null,"domain":"some.random.com","id":2216354,"path":"/flummoxer/","protocol":"https"}
```

This can more easily be seen by the fact that in my test, attempting to parse the response from my server fails:

```
MultiJson::ParseError: 783: unexpected token at 'data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

data: {"message":"Awaiting confirmation ..."}

event: successful capture
data: {"annotation_id":null,"domain":"some.random.com","id":2216354,"path":"/flummoxer/","protocol":"https"}
'
```

My server is Puma, so [it's not because I'm using Thin, as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057075/rails-actioncontrollerlive-sends-everything-at-once-instead-of-async).

What am I doing wrong? I'll provide any additional information that might be of use, if you ask.

UPDATE: The [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31238626/1888553) suggest adding both the `-N` and the `Accept:text/event-stream` header to the request. Doing so doesn't change the behavior I've described above -- the response to the request isn't sent until the call to `response.stream.close` is fired.

UPDATE 2: I've also tried hacking the `SSE#write` method to call `broadcast()` on the `Mutex::ConditionVariable` to force sending the message. This works, in the sense that it sends data immediately, but has the side effect of the curl request thinking that the stream is closed, and so no further messages are sent, which is not a stream.

UPDATE 3: I've also modified `development.rb` to include `config.allow_concurrency = true`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259163/rails-streaming-not-streaming). There's no change in the behavior described above.

Comment: I hope you noticed that you're blocking the thread when `sleep`-ing, so Puma can't do any thread related work during that time, such as sending the response, etc'... if you moved the blocking calls to another thread or to a proper scheduler, you might have a better experience.      P.S., I wrote [iodine for WebSockets and SSE](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine#eventsource--sse), so when I talk about server internals, it isn't conjuncture.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.

Presumably, that shouldn't have affected whether or not the response is sent, as the `#write()` method has already returned. Or am I missing some weird aspect of threaded servers?

The execution pause above was so I would know (watching it execute a `curl` request) if the message is being sent separately. Can you suggest a different approach to verifying it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with a basic 'out the book' Rails 5 SSE app. The issue turned out to be a Rack update that lead to buffering of the stream. More info here https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1619 and fixed by including

config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag

in config/application.rb

Comment: That is one absurdly long discussion on such a tiny topic (which being still open and without a clear resolution in sight!).

Many thanks for the sleuthing!

Comment: 3 years later and the bug is still there and not a single place in documentation mentions it :(

Comment: It is honestly crazy that I had to find this here on an out of the box rails application.

Comment: hours wasted... anguish felt... this answer appeared... and now i can breathe! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also if you use NGINX on your production, it needs special configuration for SSE to work. You should have special `location` directive in nginx config for the URL(s) with SSE controller with this settings:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_cache off;
```

Source: [EventSource / Server-Sent Events through Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672743/eventsource-server-sent-events-through-nginx)